# custom map with POI

Tags: android, drawing

I Have to implement on my app a little map of a concert hall.
it will have POI on it, I must be able to zoom, move in it etc...

I did a class that worked with a svg file converted to Picture, i extended ImageView and overwrite onDraw.

but now I've got to do the same with a 1.2Meg png, and all I get is memory error..

i use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource, and then canvas.drawBitmap(bm, canvas.getMatrix(),null)`

Does somebody has a tutorial somewhere to do so, or maybe just telling me what's wrong with my method ?

Thanks !

Renaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst a PNG file takes up 1.2MB on disk, it will be decoded into an RGB bitmap in memory, which will be much bigger. For example, an 800x600 pixel 24-bit RGB bitmap takes up just under 1.4MB of memory, whereas it might be as small as 30kB when compressed down to PNG.

The solution is to only render the subsection of the map that you can currently see on screen.

To make this easier, you could split your source image into chunks exactly 1/4 the size of your screen. This ensures that, at all times, there will be no more than 9 of these smaller images loaded into memory:

```
+--+----------+--------+
|1 |    2     |   3    |
+--+----------+--------+
|  |          |        |
|4 |    5     |   6    |
|  |          |        |
|  |          |        |
+--+----------+--------+
|  |          |        |
|7 |    8     |   9    |
|  |          |        |
+--+----------+--------+
```

When the images are perfectly aligned, you'll only need to have 4 images in memory. For optimisation as you scroll around, you can pre-fetch images in the direction of scrolling.

If your map is 10000x10000 pixels and your screen is 480x800, expand the image's edges to have a while or black (or whatever background colour you like!) edge, such that it can be split evenly. In this case, you'd use 10080x10400.

Comment: hum, but what about zoom/unzoom, at the begining, the entier png is seen on screen, do I must have numerous sources in different quality, and switch the source in function of my zoom (a pinch zoom, no buttons)

Comment: You could support fixed zoom levels. Generate a set of images for each level, where the top level is a scaled down version of the entire image, the next level is two or three times as large, etc.